# Svydesign: analyzing complex surveys

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, survey

I´ve been analyzing a survey from the Dominican Republica called ENHOGAR 2021, for that I used:

- survey
- srvyr

The issue here is that my dataset has both weights and probabilities identified as "Factor_ expansión" and "Factor_ponderación" respectively.

I understand that for the  `as_survey_design()` function to work you need one or the other, so you have to create two objects one with weights and one with probs.

Is there a way where I can use both variables in  `as_survey_design()` function?

Comment: hi, is this microdata public?  are you able to review the technical documentation and figure out the clustering and strata variables?  if they published any R, stata, sas, sudaan, or spss code, that might make it easier to determine how to create svydesign() in R..

Comment: My Spanish isn't great, but it looks to me as though the `ponderación` might be normalised somehow (eg, to add to sample size, for approximately correct standard errors from standard methods) and the `expansión` add to the population size. So in R you'd just need the `expansión`.  Easy to check: first, plot the two weights against each other and see if it's a straight line. Second, look at the sum of each set of weights.  https://www.one.gob.do/publicaciones/2022/informe-general-enhogar-2021/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have downloaded some data from the survey.  Here is a scatterplot of the two weight variables [image]

and here's a summary of them

```
> summary(a$F_expansión)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
   3.268   45.688   76.628  124.666  128.420 9385.545 
> summary(a$F_Pondera)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.02621  0.36649  0.61467  1.00000  1.03011 75.28567 
> sum(a$F_expansión)
[1] 10568913
```

The two sets of weights contain the same information, except that the `ponderación` weights are scaled to have unit mean and the `expansión` weights sum to what is plausibly the size of the sampling frame (Google says 11 million for the national population).  If you were using software such as SPSS or Excel that doesn't understand sampling weights, you could use `ponderación` as the weights and get approximately correct inference for everything except totals: means, proportions, quantiles, regression coefficients, etc.

If you want to estimate totals you need the `expansión` weights. In the R survey package (or the `srvyr` wrapper) you should just use the `expansión` weights, because the package can handle sampling weights correctly.  The same holds if you're using SUDAAN or Stata or SPSS Complex Samples or the various SAS PROC SURVEYwhatevers.

*Update*: I have checked with a Latin American colleague and these seem to be standard terms: 'pesos de expansion' for the raw weights and 'pesos ponderados' for scaled weights